# NGINX REVERSE PROXY AND PORT 445

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to implement a reverse proxy that through port 445 allows me to exchange data with a NAS server.
Let me explain, with windows explorer I want to go to the reverse proxy address 111.0.0.111:445 and this takes me to the shared folder. I've been looking for a solution for days but nothing.
More Info: Ubuntu 18.04 on VM.
Thanks!
I try this configuration on /etc/nginx/sites-available.

```
stream {
       upstream {
        server nasIP:445
        }
server {
        listen 445;
        listen listen [::]:445;
        server_name _;
        location / {
                    proxy_pass storage:445;
                   }
        }
}
```

When i try to restart nginx,receive this message:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "stream" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:37
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: SMB isn’t HTTP.

Comment: @DanielB yes i know,so i can't do that?